# How can I improve my ladder logic diagram of a vending machine?

Tags: boolean-algebra, plc, programmable-logic

I am trying to create a coffee and tea machine using a ladder logic diagram. There are small, medium, and large sizes. This is where I am now:

[image]

Can you give me any ideas or corrections on how to improve the diagram and make it more efficient?

Comment: why do you think that it needs improvement?

Comment: I want to add coin detector and calculations so it can return change. I have been trying to figure out how to add that in the ladder. Is it even possible to do it?

Comment: 1) As it’s currently programmed, it won’t ever stop dispensing the requested drink until ”stop” is manually pressed. 2) If the user presses both ”coffee” and ”tea”, the machine will dispense both simultaneously. 3) Usually the heater would be timer controlled, only turning off after a period of inactivity 4) coin counting and handling logic is missing

Comment: 5) detection of the presence of water, paper cups and enough space in the waste container before a purchase can be made. 6) Detection of coffee when coffee is ordered, and tea when tea is ordered, before a purchase is allowed

Comment: Add your comments to your question, since it is the basis of your question!

Comment: @jms, that's should be posted as an answer along with a copy of the current program in case the question gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

It will not work . No button to select small, medium or large....modify and start over.

Comment: It will work. You can put in any size container and it will keep filling until someone presses STOP!